# Why Domain Admin Cannot Enable Domain Wide Delegation for Service Accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, oauth

We need to use service accounts for our application instead of individually end users to call some Google Apis such as Admin Directory Api. There are 3 members of this project which are me as owner, our domain admin as service account admin and service account as service account user. Based on my research, we need to enable domain wide delegation through Google Api Console or Google Cloud Platform to grant access our service account and only domain admin can enable this. I have limited permissions but even our admin has full permissions cannot enable this field. Anyone knows what the reason is?

Answer (score 1):

There are several types (levels) of G Suite Admin: [Mobile, Services, Help Desk, User Management, Groups, Super] Admin. Notice that there is no `Domain Admin` in that list.

You need to make your admin a `Super Admin`. Double check the permissions that you have applied to your admin in the [G Suite Console](https://gsuite.google.com).

To enable G Suite Delegation follow this document:

[Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation)